# Steam API Получить инвентарь человека

Tags: php, steam

Добрый день господа, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Раньше делал парсер инвентаря пользователя, было все отлично. Теперь пытаюсь спарсить инвентарь, в итоге после 3й перезагрузки страници стим не отвечает, и начинает отдавать ответ только после минуты ожидания. Как быть? если сайтом будет пользоваться допустим человек 10, то инвентарь в таком случае вообще парситься не будет. Если что, контент беру так - file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$id.'/inventory/json/730/2'); Была мысль пускать запрос через ТОР, при каждом запросе меняя цепь, тем самым меняя IP адрес, но это же костыль.

Comment: Так а это не оно? Или есть еще способ парсить инвентарь? Если да - можете скинуть ссылку, буду очень признателен

Comment: Мне бы для инветаря, вот смотрю везде используют метод как я http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142591/get-csgo-inventory-with-steam-api

Comment: У меня есть АПИ кей, я авторизацию делал через стим. Мне именно инвентарь нужен

Comment: Да, действительно, этот endpoint также позиционируется, как api, извините =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы вы прочитали код ошибки, всё бы сами поняли:

> The request is a duplicate and the action has already occurred in the past, ignored this time (29)

Система знает, что вы недавно запрашивали точно этот ресурс и запрещает вам спамить её одинаковыми запросами.

Вам просто необходимо кешировать результаты всех запросов

---

Чтобы получить тело ответа при возникновении ошибки
нужно передать в `file_get_contents` контекст с параметром:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('ignore_errors' => true),
));

$result = file_get_contents($uri, false, $context);  
$data = json_decode($result, true);
if (!empty($data['error'])) {
  throw new \Exception("SteamAPI Error: {$data['error']}");
}
```

---

ЗЫ:
`Expires` заголовок у них шикарнейший:

> Expires:Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT

Comment: Секундочку, вы вероятно не получаете тело ответа с ошибкой) Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: А можно поподробнее про заголовок. Он типа отдает дату/время, когда можно сделать повторный запрос?

Comment: Этот заголовок должен отдавать дату в будущем, до которой можно безболезненно кешировать ответ, браузер делает это автоматически, например. Но в steam, этот заголовок бесполезен, потому что 1997)

Comment: Думаю можно кешировать запросы в каком-нибудь redis на пару минут. От бедности можно и файлы с ответами создавать.